# Is there a way to use GAS to identify which Google Sheets are pulling info via importrange from the target Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm trying to do a security audit, and I want to see what *other* Sheets are pulling data from different "source" Sheets.

Is there a way to do this using Google Apps Script?

I've Googled and also asked on the Google Sheets forum but haven't been able to come up with anything.

And if so, is there a way to revoke access to specific Sheets?

Comment: The permission is linked to the user account having privileges to the source spreadsheet(say, ss) and not the ss itself. Officially provided way to remove access is by removing the user who gave access from the ss.